# Saving a form model with using MultiWidget and a MultiValueField

Tags: django, django-forms, django-multiwidget

I'm trying to understand how to create forms by subclassing MultiWidgets and MultiValueFields.
I have a simple Address model and associated forms:

```
class Address(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    state = models.CharField(choices = settings.STATES, max_length=50)
    postal = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    address = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Addresses'

class AddressFieldWidget(forms.MultiWidget):
    def decompress(self,value):
        if value:
            return [value[0],value[1],value[2]]
        return ''

    def format_output(self, rendered_widgets):
        str = ''
        line_1 = '<td class="align_left"><label for="contact_phone">Address Line 1</label></td>'

        for field in rendered_widgets:
            str += '<tr>' + line_1
            str += '<td class="align_right">%s</td></tr>' % field
        return '<tr>' + str + '</tr>'

    def value_from_datadict(self,data,files,name):
        line_list = [widget.value_from_datadict(data,files,name+'_%s' %i) for i,widget in enumerate(self.widgets)]
        try:
            return line_list[0] + ' ' + line_list[1] + ' ' + line_list[2]       
        except:
            return ''

class AddressField(forms.MultiValueField):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        fields = (
            forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'big'})),
            forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'big'})),
            forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'big'})),
        )
        super(AddressField,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.widget = AddressFieldWidget(widgets=[fields[0].widget, fields[1].widget, fields[2].widget])

    def compress(self, data_list):
        return data_list[0] + ' ' + data_list[1] + ' ' + data_list[2]


class AddressFormNew(forms.ModelForm):
    postal = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'small'}))
    address = AddressField()
    city = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'big'}))

    class Meta:
        model = Address
```

Well I can't figure out how to use this form in my view. I'm trying to do :

```
@login_required
def render_addresses(request):
    address_form = AddressFormNew()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        address_form = AddressFormNew(request.POST)
        if address_form.is_valid():
            address_form.save()
            return HttpResponse('ok')
        else:
            return HttpResponse(address_form.errors['address'])

    return render_to_response('profile/addresses.html',context_instance=RequestContext(request,{'address_form':address_form}))
```

As a result, Django gives me this error:

> Enter a list of values.

Also, when I try to print request.POST.items(), it gives address response as 3 seperated datas.

I'm quite lost here, I have to get my address data in one line. How should I achieve that by only saving my form ?

I really appreciate that if someone gives me a clear explanation.

Answer (score 5):

Here are the issues that I see in your code which should solve it:

(1). In your AddressField **init** method when you are calling the **init** of super class, you should pass **fields** as argument.

> ```
> class AddressField(forms.MultiValueField):
>     def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
>         fields = (
>             forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'big'})),
>             forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'big'})),
>             forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'big'})),
>         )
>         self.widget = AddressFieldWidget(widgets=[fields[0].widget, fields[1].widget, fields[2].widget])
>         super(AddressField,self).__init__(fields=fields,*args,**kwargs)
> ```

(2). You are correct, your value_from_datadict is incorrect. The point is that, you have used a MultiValueField to get populated by the widget. So the widget must return a list of values to the corresponding sub-fields in AddressField

You can just call the **value_from_datadict** of the the super class and that will do the job, or use this (which i think is the same):

> ```
> def value_from_datadict(self,data,files,name):
>      res = []
>      for i, widget in enumerate(self.widgets):
>          res.append(widget.value_from_datadict(data, files, name + '_%s' % i))
>      return res
> ```

Its important to understand the underlying concept. You could have used this widget with a CharField too. In that case the value_from_datadict should have returned a string. But since you are using MultiValueField, the return type should be a list. That is the very reason for getting the "enter a list of values" as error

Just an additional thought, you should not use space as delimiter if you are planning to re-create address line1, 2 and 3 from values stored in database to a form. If not then all is good :)

I did not find good examples for MultiValueField and MultiWidget in documentation or on the net, but since I had to use them in one of my projects, I had to dig into it myself. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

i think you also need a decompress method, and fields = (...) should be outside of `__init__`

Comment: i have a decompress method, i think value_from_datadict causes the problem but i don't have any idea how to use it ?

Answer (score -1):

Django's source files can often be a good source of inspiration. (Pun not intended) You could for instance check out `django.forms.fields.SplitDateTimeField`, which gives an example of how to do something similar.

Some possible errors could be that you are setting self.widget after you initialize (`super(AddressField,self).__init__()`), so the field just uses the standard widget. And you didn't send `fields` in with the `__init__`either. Here's a quick draft of how I think you could do `AddressField`:

```
class AddressField(forms.MultiValueField):
    widget = MultiValueWidget(widgets=(forms.TextInput, forms.TextInput, forms.TextInput)
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        fields = (
            forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'big'})),
            forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'big'})),
            forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'big'})),
        )
        super(AddressField,self).__init__(fields, *args, **kwargs)

    def compress(self, data_list):
        return "%s %s %s" % data_list[0:2]
```

This excludes all the mumbo-jumbo you had in `AddressFieldWidget`, because I frankly didn't quite understand what you were trying to do :)